# Sequelize using MySQL dialect failed to generate foreign key while migrating models

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, command, sequelize.js, constraints

- I am using **commands of sequelize** to create and migrate Models to
  generate Tables in MySql database.
- To generate new model: `sequelize model:create --name Demo --attributes column:string`
- And After the **Model** and **migration** file generate, adding few lines of code to make **association and foreign key constraints** using given snippet of code:
- In Derived/Child Table of Comapny:

```
      Employee.associate = function (models) {
            // associations can be defined here
            Employee.belongsTo(models.Company, {
                foreignKey: "companyId",
                onDelete: "CASCADE"
            })
        };
```

- In Base/Parent table Comapany:

  ```
      Company.associate = function (models) {
          // associations can be defined here
          Company.hasMany(models.Employee,{
              foreignKey:"companyId",
          })
      };
  ```

But it does not reflect in **Table->ALTER TABLE->ForeignKey Constraints**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign keys are messed up.... i think it should look something more like below because you want a field called companyId to be in your employee table that references the id field of the company table

```
Employee.associate = function (models) {
            // associations can be defined here
            Employee.belongsTo(models.Company, {
                sourceKey: "companyId",
                foreignKey: "id",
                onDelete: "CASCADE"
            })
        };
```

and

```
Company.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Company.hasMany(models.Employee,{
            foreignKey:"companyId",
        })
    };
```

this one will just assume your source key is your primary key which is probably id

Answer (score 0):

- The foreign key constraint will reflect to the MySQL DB and its
  table, only when we change migration file too along with model file.
- We have to add in migration file like:

  ```
  companyId:{
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      references: {
          model: "Comapany",
          key: "id"
      }
    },
  ```
- It worked successfully for me.